# Firewalld fails on completely new Debian 12 server

Tags: debian, firewalld, debian-bookworm

My Debian 12 Bookworm VPS was running firewalld 1.3.0-1 without problems. Due to unrelated issues, I had to rebuild the server, and now firewalld fails.

I use ansible, so the configuration should be identical to before. Maybe some apt dependencies have changed in the interim.

To troubleshoot more easily, here is a reproduction:

- I created a **brand new VPS** with my hosting company; debian 12
- I logged in as root
- `$ apt install firewalld --yes`
- `$ systemctl status firewalld.service`

```
ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: No such file or directory; did you mean chain ‘nat_PREROUTING’ in table inet ‘firewalld’?
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
Error: No such file or directory; did you mean chain ‘nat_POSTROUTING’ in table inet ‘firewalld’?
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
...etc.
```

My intention is to use iptables instead of nftables (a docker limitation), so:

- I edited `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.config` and replaced `FirewallBackend=nftables` with `FirewallBackend=iptables`
- `$ systemctl restart firewalld.service`
- `$ systemctl status firewalld.service`

```
ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.8.9 (nf_tables): 
CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain PREROUTING
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain PREROUTING
CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain POSTROUTING
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain POSTROUTING
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain POSTROUTING
CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain OUTPUT
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain OUTPUT
RULE_APPEND failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain OUTPUT
...etc.
```

I don't understand as it was working before. And as you can see this is a **completely new server**, with nothing installed and nothing else configured. I expected it to work "out of the box".

What have I done wrongly?

(Also posted to [repo](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/1184).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it by simply rebooting.

Then `$ systemctl status firewalld.service` shows that firewalld is running:

```
Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-08-07 04:34:46 UTC; 31s ago
```

How unexpected!

Comment: Author said [on repo](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/1184#issuecomment-1668290601) that this is unexpected, and could be an upstream issue.